# Getting Count() of navigation property without loading whole collection in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, xaml, eager-loading, navigation-properties

In XAML DataGrid is bound to a list of EF entities called `Results`. One of columns is bound to `Count` of `Buildings` navigation property. Lazy loading is off. So I need to include `Buildings` in query, to get it's count. This causes a performance issues because whole `Buildings` entity collection loads in memory. But I just need a `Count` of it. Is there any way to get `Count` of navigation property without loading it in memory?

```
  var resQuery =
                db.BAStreets
                    .Include("Street.StreetType")
                    .Include("Area.District")
                    .Include("Buildings")
                    .Where(x => true);
  Results = resQuery.ToList();
```

Binding in XAML:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Buildings.Count}"/>
```

And little additional question.  I use this: `.Where(x => true)` to cast DbSet to IQueryable. Looks like this is a smell thing. What is standard pattern?

Comment: To your additional question; either just use the type returned anyway (and never mind that it's more precise than strictly needed, it'll still implement `IQueryable<T>`) or in the few cases where that doesn't work, use `.AsQueryable()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just need the `Count` then you could create following Query

```
Results = db.BAStreets.Select(i => new
                                {
                                    Street = i,
                                    StreetType = i.Street.StreetType,
                                    District = i.Area.District,
                                    BuildingCount = i.Buildings.Count()
                                }).ToList()
```

Then in XAML you bind to the `BuildingCount` property instead of the other.

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Street}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding StreetType }"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding District }"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding BuildingCount }"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Being more familiar with LINQ than Entity Frameowrk, but couldn't you just use the `.Count()` method instead of `.ToList()`?

Comment: The `.Count` is only for Buildings, not for BAStreets. He wants the Count for each BAStreet and not the total number of Buildings for any instance in the database